# Cake PHP Password Reset

Tags: php, cakephp

currently working on a password reset script for a CakePHP application that I have been put in charge of.

So far, I have a forgot script that I created a random string, adding this to the relevant user and emailing the user with a link to reset. (the domain name is in fact the live one)

```
Click on the link below to Reset Your Password


Click here to Reset Your Password
or Visit this Link

domainnamehere/users/reset/e9bb0ab37ff9175a856f0aff3e18db801451306e5a50bfc618c43280b62628e4bdb8131b638e042b47d42ca1516de11f1b025d646406bfd31054db167d5ef430#62442a331b1f9a3e37cbb9a33c1d619b8a8e0a18

This email was sent using the CakePHP Framework
```

Upon clicking the reset and loading the reset form, it seems to be skipping right to my last else statement with no token value?

```
function reset($token=null){
    //$this->layout="Login";
    $this->User->recursive=-1;
    if(!empty($token)){
        $u=$this->User->findBytokenhash($token);
        if($u){
            $this->User->id=$u['User']['id'];
            if(!empty($this->data)){
                $this->User->data=$this->data;
                $this->User->data['User']['username']=$u['User']['username'];
                $new_hash=sha1($u['User']['username'].rand(0,100));//created token
                $this->User->data['User']['tokenhash']=$new_hash;
                if($this->User->validates(array('fieldList'=>array('password','password_retype')))){
                    if($this->User->save($this->User->data))
                    {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Password Has been Updated');
                        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Error updating values');
                    }

                }
                else{

                    $this->set('errors',$this->User->invalidFields());
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Token Corrupted,,Please Retry.the reset link work only for once.');
        }
    }
    else{
        // $this->redirect('/');
      $this->Session->setFlash($token);
    }
}
```

reset.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
   <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'reset')); ?>
   <fieldset>
      <legend><?php echo __('Change your Password'); ?></legend>
      <?php
      //debug($users);
      echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'Change password'));
      echo $this->Form->input('password_retype', array('label' => 'Confirm password', 'type' => 'password'));
      ?>
   </fieldset>
   <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

any help on this situation would be much appreciated as I am stuck, thanks!

Comment: I'm confused, are you calling your forgot() or your reset()?

Comment: Would also be useful to see how the function is called, since you are not getting the `$token` parameter back.

Comment: I am calling my reset, the forgot function is working fine. Would you like to see the .ctp file?

Comment: Yes please. Also delete the forgot function of the question, it isn't necessary here apparently. If the .ctp file is too large, just post the form (and submit) part.

Comment: Edited the question for you, thanks. Basically, it just always goes to the last else and I don't know why

Comment: I hope that the actual reset token is a little more secure than the token hash generated in the reset method? There is practically no randomness, all an attacker needs would be the username and a maximum of 100 retries. Just in case, I'd recommend to use for example [**Security::generateAuthKey()**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Security.html#_generateAuthKey) to generate something more random.

Answer (score 3):

Well,... you are not sending the token back when you submit...

You do

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'reset')); ?>
```

and that submits the form to `users/reset`, not `users/reset/token`. So, either pass the token along with the action submit like this

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'reset', $token)); ?>
```

or submit it along with the form as hidden input

```
  <?php
  //debug($users);
  echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'Change password'));
  echo $this->Form->input('password_retype', array('label' => 'Confirm password', 'type' => 'password'));

  //here
  echo $this->Form->input('token', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$token)
  ?>
```

and get it in the controller like

```
if (!empty($token) && !empty($this->request->data['User']['token'])) {
```

In the future, don't expect forms to submit all the values you passed by url, it's not how things work :(

***Security tip***

If I were evil, or if Voldemort knew internet, he could try to do call your reset url with random tokens to change passwords to `voldi-rocks` and then try and access the site. I recommend having a valid time for the reset token, if the reset link isn't used within one hour (for example), invalidate it.

***Tip of the day***

You can put `public $recursive = -1;` on your User model to avoid putting it on every action in the controller.

Comment: This is great, I have now got the system going through the process however for some reason, the code for actually updating the password in the database isn't updating anything? Even though no errors are shown? Any thoughts? thanks.

Comment: That's an entirely different question an should be posted as such (after you do a through search an try to solve it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

we found out that you have to summit in the reset.ctp the rest of the required fields shown in the registration form, hidden of course, and everything works perfect, including updating the password field.

Answer (score 0):

```
function admin_forgotpwd() {

        if (count($this->Session->read("Auth.User"))) {
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }

        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Forgot Password');

        $this->layout = 'admin_login';
        $this->User->recursive = -1;
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            if (empty($this->data['User']['email'])) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Please enter your email.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
            } else {
                $email = $this->data['User']['email'];
                $fu = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.email' => $email)));
                if ($fu) {
                    //debug($fu);
                    if ($fu['User']['user_status'] == 'active') {
                        $key = Security::hash(String::uuid(), 'sha512', true);
                        $hash = sha1($fu['User']['username'] . rand(0, 100));
                        $url = Router::url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'reset'), true) . '/' . $key . '#' . $hash;
                        $ms = $url;
                        $ms = wordwrap($ms, 1000);
                        debug($url);
                        $fu['User']['tokenhash'] = $key;
                        $this->User->id = $fu['User']['id'];
                        if ($this->User->saveField('tokenhash', $fu['User']['tokenhash'])) {




                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Check your email to reset password.', true), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
                            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
                            //============EndEmail=============//
                        } else {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__("Error while generating reset link."), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('This account is not active yet.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Email does not exist'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```